# pandas rolling window mean in the future

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-average

I would like to use the [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) method on a data frame with datetime to aggregate future values.
It looks it can be done only in the past, is it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you can use shift to move you calculation back in time.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':np.arange(0,11,1)},index=pd.date_range('2018-07-23',periods=11))

df['rolling'] = df.rolling('2D').mean().shift(-1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
            Data  rolling
2018-07-23     0      0.5
2018-07-24     1      1.5
2018-07-25     2      2.5
2018-07-26     3      3.5
2018-07-27     4      4.5
2018-07-28     5      5.5
2018-07-29     6      6.5
2018-07-30     7      7.5
2018-07-31     8      8.5
2018-08-01     9      9.5
2018-08-02    10      NaN
```

Comment: The shift(-1) doesn't work well in case you have holes in your dates, which might sometimes be the case.

Comment: Fill your series with missing dates then shift.  Maybe. @gvo

Comment: Well, filling with what? For a min or a max, it's quite easy, for a sum as well, but for a mean... Not that much. 
And it's very related to the aggregation you which to do, which might or might not be not that clean.

Comment: @gvo Yes, understood.

Comment: This does not work as intended!
We want to have a roll over some defined time range after the series index times.
But instead we receive for each time index, what happened a defined time range before the next index time!

Comment: @Antalagor It doesn't work as *you* intended?   Please post a new question with sample data and expected output.  I am sure the SO community can help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
series.sort_index(ascending=False).rolling("2D").mean().sort_index()
```

you can reorder the series. the rolling window edges care about series order not about time order.